# How can i count transactions executed in a day in mysql workbench?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I just want to learn how to count queries executed in a day on mysql workbench. THANKS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's things like `SHOW ENGINE InnoDB STATUS` which gives you a staggering amount of detail and insight into the engine, but there's a summary near the bottom that looks like this:

```
Number of rows inserted 67871639, updated 554629050, deleted 65687644, read 1072151182312
```

That might be what you're looking for.

The alternative to that is the general query log, but that can quickly exhaust your disk space if not rotated.

**Update**: There's also this:

```
SHOW GLOBAL STATUS LIKE "Questions";
```

That's the number of queries run, but isn't broken out by type. It increments from server start, so you'll have to record this on a daily basis and account for times when it gets reset.

Comment: Can it be more specific?  I need to monitor the number of transaction users execute within the day. Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: The general query log logs *everything*, and as such it gets huge in a hurry. You could basically count lines in there. There might be other counters inside the InnoDB stats, so poke around.

Comment: I found a reference to the `GLOBAL STATUS` variable `Questions` which might help.

Comment: Thank you. I really appreciate it. I'll try to look around for more counters and maybe stumble on something really on-point. I'm just new to this environment. Thanks